# How to extract the time from the who command

Tags: unix, cut

what is the best way to extract the login time for a particular user using the who command.
I was thinking you can do:

```
who | cut -d " " -f(some number but you dont know which one).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$ who
me   tty1         2014-07-25 10:06 (:0)
me   pts/0        2014-07-25 10:06 (:0.0)
me   pts/1        2014-07-25 13:43 (:0.0)

$ who | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3,4
2014-07-25 10:06
2014-07-25 10:06
2014-07-25 13:43
```

`tr -s ' '` squeezes spaces (many become just one). Then `cut` slices the text in blocks based on space and prints the 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command too:

```
 $ who | awk '{print $3,$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely shortest/simplest solution:

```
who | cuts 2 3
```

you can find [***cuts on github***](http://arielf.github.io/cuts) (full disclosure: I wrote it)